# Sharding and replication in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, replication, sharding

I have to use the sharding and replication in MongoDB.
What is the minimum hardware requirement including RAM ?
And is there any simulator to insert the data in MongoDB?

Comment: This question is off-topic on SO (which is aimed at programming, not programmers questions) and would be better suited on http://dba.staxkexchange.com ***if*** you added a whole lot more information like use cases, average size of expected documents for each use case executed, number of expected use case executions per day or hour. Basically everything you can possibly provide. As for document generation, please have a look at https://github.com/rueckstiess/mtools/wiki/mgenerate